# curl_easy_perform program in C

Tags: c, curl

Now, after doing the changes in code I am able to send the POST resquest to SERVER and even server is sending the response. But now my program hangs at curl_easy_perform function. Do you have any idea?

curl -H "Authorization: Basic dGVzdENsaWVudDp0ZXN0U2VjcmV0" -X POST "http://x.x.x.x:8080/authservice/token?grant_type=client_credential"

**My program:**

```
struct url_data {
    size_t size;
    char* data;
};
static size_t write_data(char *buffer, size_t size, size_t nitems, void *userp)
{
    struct url_data *data = (struct url_data *)userp;
    size_t index = data->size;
    size_t n = (size * nitems);
    data->size += (size * nitems);
    char* tmp = realloc(data->data, data->size + 1);
    if(tmp) {
        data->data = tmp;
    } else {
        if(data->data) free(data->data);
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate memory.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    memcpy(data->data + index, buffer, n);
    data->data[data->size] = '\0';
    return size * nitems;
}

int main(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    long http_code = 0;
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;
    struct curl_slist *slist=NULL;

    struct url_data data;
    data.size = 0;
    data.data = (char*) malloc(4096); /* reasonable size initial buffer */
    bzero(data.data, 4096);
    //curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://x.x.x.x:8080/authservice/token?grant_type=client_credential");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "libcurl-agent/1.0");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &data);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);


        slist = curl_slist_append(slist, "Authorization: Basic dGVzdENsaWVudDp0ZXN0U2VjcmV0");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, slist);
        slist = curl_slist_append(slist, "Content-Type:application/json");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, slist);
        slist = curl_slist_append(slist, "Content-Length: 0");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, slist);
        slist = curl_slist_append(slist, "Expect:");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, slist);

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);

        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        /* Check for errors */
        if(res != CURLE_OK) {
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",     curl_easy_strerror(res));
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "Data:[%s] Ret:[%s]\n", data.data, curl_easy_strerror(res));
        }
        res = curl_easy_getinfo (curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE, &http_code);
        printf("http_code:%ld\n", http_code);
        /* always cleanup */
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        if(data.data) free(data.data);

        curl_slist_free_all(slist);
    }
    //curl_global_cleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
* About to connect() to x.x.x.x port 8080 (#0)
*   Trying x.x.x.x...
* connected
* Connected to x.x.x.x (x.x.x.x) port 8080 (#0)
> POST /authservice/token?grant_type=client_credential HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: libcurl-agent/1.0
Host: x.x.x.x:8080
Accept: */*
Authorization: Basic dGVzdENsaWVudDp0ZXN0U2VjcmV0
Content-Type:application/json
Content-Length: 0
```

Comment: Run the command-line curl in verbose mode and see what headers it sends.

Comment: > POST /authservice/token?grant_type=client_credentials HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.24.0 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.24.0 NSS/3.14.3.0 zlib/1.2.5 libidn/1.24 libssh2/1.4.1
> Host: 159.99.186.245:8080
> Accept: */*
> Authorization: Basic dGVzdENsaWVudDp0ZXN0U2VjcmV0
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Content-Type: application/xml;charset=UTF-8
< Content-Language: en-US
< Content-Length: 297
< Date: Wed, 02 Mar 2016 11:13:42 GMT

Comment: *See* what it sends, don't *show*.

Comment: I hope your program #include's the appropriate header files.  Those statements should have been part of the post.   Then we do not have to guess.

Comment: this line: `printf("http_code:%d\n", http_code);` should be: `printf("http_code:%ld\n", http_code);`  so the format specifier matches the type of the `http_code` parameter.

Comment: I ran the posted code, using `localhost` and referencing port `80` rather than `8080` as I have my server very limited on which ports are allowed.  It ran with no crashes, but did indicate: `The requested URL /authservice/token was not found on this server`

Comment: After doing the below changes, now my request is start reaching server successfully and even server is sending the response. But now my program is getting stuck at curl_easy_perform.

Comment: FWIW: `grant_type=client_credential` suggests OAuth 2.0 but the actual name of the grant and parameter is `client_credentials` with a trailing "s" so if your server is a standards compliant OAuth 2.0 Authorization Server you should probably change that

Comment: When I checked my program in **pstack**, then it was stuck at curl_easy_perform. After that I did CTRL+D, then my program is able to receive the output. What could be the reason? Any option I have to include in my program?